# Why if $X \subset A$ has codimension $1$, the only subspace properly containing $X$ is $A$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

I saw the following question a while ago on Math.SE [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651154/why-is-f-continuous-if-its-kernel-is-not-dense-in-a).

The answer provided seems to give a satisfactory result, but one thing in the answer I can not quite see. The author of the answer states that

> Since $X$ has codimension $1$, the only subspace properly containing $X$ is $A$.

I can not seem to see why this is true. Am I missing something? Can anyone please elaborate as to why this is true?

Comment: If $X$ is closed, I do believe this is true. If it is not closed, then it is definitely not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The codimension of $X$ is the dimension of $A/X$, which is one. The subspaces of $A$ containing $X$ are in correspondence with the subspaces of $A/X$ (see below), of which there are only two: the trivial subspace and all of $A/X$.

---

Let $S(A/X)$ be the set of all subspaces of the vector space $A/X$ and let $S(A;X)$ be the set of all subspaces of $A$ containing $X$. Define a map $$\phi:S(A;X) \to S(A/X)$$ by $\phi(U) = \{ u+X \mid u \in U\}$.

To see that $\phi$ is injective, assume that $\phi(U) = \phi(V)$. Then if $u \in U$, we have $u+X \in \phi(U) = \phi(V)$, so $u+X = v + X$ for some $v \in V$. Therefore $u-v \in X \subseteq V$, so that $u \in V$. By a symmetrical argument we conclude that $U = V$.

Now we show that $\phi$ is surjective. Let $W$ be any subspace of $A/X$. Let $U = \pi^{-1}(W)$, where $\pi:A \to A/X$ is the canonical projection. This $U$ is a subspace of $A$, and moreover it contains $X$ because $\pi(x) = 0_{A/X} \in W$ for any $x \in X$. In fact, $\phi(U) = W$ because

$$\phi(U) = \{u+X \mid u \in \pi^{-1}(W)\} = \{\pi(u) \mid u \in \pi^{-1}(W)\} = W.$$

Comment: Does this imply that $A$ is the only subspace properly containing $X$? I apologize, I'm very new to the concept of codimensions

Comment: @DJS Are you familiar with the concept of quotient spaces?

Comment: I am familiar with quotient spaces yes :) .

Comment: @DJS As far as I know the most natural definition of the codimension for infinite-dimensional spaces is the one I gave. If you're ok with that then the rest shouldn't be too hard: $A/X$ has dimension one, so it only has two subspaces. By the [correspondence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_(group_theory)), there are exactly two subspaces of $A$ which contain $X$, namely $X$ and $A$.

Comment: I am sorry to come back to this question after such a long while. But can you please explain to me how the Correspondence Theorem tells us that the subspaces of $A$ containing $X$ are in correspondence with the subspaces of $A/X$ ?

Comment: @DJS I edited in a proof of the correspondence. Does that help?